# zepto trigger not work

Tags: javascript, triggers, mouseevent, zepto

I bind a click event for '.a' div

```
$('.a').on('click',()=>{
   //something
});
```

and another click event for '.b' to trigger '.a' click event:

```
$('.b').on('click',()=>{
   //something
   $('.a').trigger('click');
});
```

but trigger click does not work.
if I trigger twice, it's work,like this:

```
 $('.b').on('click',()=>{
   //something
   $('.a').trigger('click');
   $('.a').trigger('click');
});
```

I don't know why, and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Use the `<>` snippet editor

Answer (score -1):

Try next code. Hope you use Jquery.

```
$('.a').click();
```

Comment: That is basically a short cut for trigger() under the hood